# If Statement proper formula

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked on here about if statements. I have found a few things but I am having issues figuring out the proper statement formula.

I have 2 tables in the database with the following 2 fields

```
table 1
rct_app_id

table 2
uid
```

now if the uid field matches the rct_app_id field I want it to

```
echo "Green Light";
```

if they don't match

```
echo "No Go"
```

this is my formula

```
<?php

      $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM recruits WHERE rct_app_uid = {$user_id}";
      $result = query($sql);

      $rct_app_id = ['rct_app_id'];

      if ($rct_app_id == 'uid') {

          echo  "Green Light";

      } else {

          echo  "No Go";
    }

?>

function query($query)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
```

Comment: `if ($rct_app_id == 'uid') {` in this line what is 'uid' ? Is it session value or field value of table2's uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. but keep in mind its hard for people to figure out whats going on by bits and pieces and it makes it harder to help you.

```
<?php

          $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM recruits WHERE rct_app_uid = {$user_id}";
          $result = query($sql);

          while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))!=false){

              $rct_app_id = $row['rct_app_id'];

          if ($rct_app_id == $user_id) {

              echo  "Green Light";

          } else {

              echo  "No Go";
        }

     }
      }     
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix two lines. $result has the results from the database, so that's the source for the rct_app_id data.  Then, when you do the comparison, you need to compare the two variables.

```
 $rct_app_id = $result['rct_app_id'];

  if ($rct_app_id == $user_id) {
```

The way you have it, you're comparing an array to a string.

When you do this:

```
  $rct_app_id = ['rct_app_id'];
```

You're actually setting the variable $rct_app_id equal to an array with one element, although the syntax is incorrect. Instead, you need to get one element of the array that is returned from the database. This assumes that you have a function called query() that is working properly and returning an array.

Instead, we need to set the variable equal to one element of the array like so:

```
$rct_app_id = $result['rct_app_id'];
```

Then, when you do a comparison like this:

```
  if ($rct_app_id == 'uid') {
```

you're saying if the variable $rct_app_id is equal to the string uid, which it's not. Variables always start with $ in php, strings are quoted. The variable set earlier in the script is $user_id (from SESSION), so we need to compare to that:

```
  if ($rct_app_id == $user_id)
```

Comment: larsAnders it gives error    Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: Ah, so $result is an object, not an array. You need to use the object's methods to get an array out of it, like so:  `$result = query($sql);  $res_array = $result->fetch_assoc();   $rct_app_id = $res_array['rct_app_id'];`

Comment: Ok, so backing up, do you have a function called `query()` and if so, can you post the code of that function?

Comment: larsAnders I'm using mysqli

Comment: Not seeing an update - are you sure you updated the question?

Comment: larsAnders query function    global $connection;    return mysqli_query($connection, $query);

Comment: K, I'm handing this off to @GregBorbonus. His answer will work for mysqli

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You've specified your sql lib, I've edited the answer below to work with your updated answer.

Since you didn't specify the library, I'm making the answer and the code edits with the assumption that you're using mysql. Though all queries and return functions use similar syntax, ie: mysql_fetch_assoc() = mysqli_fetch_assoc(), pg_fetch_assoc(postgres).

```
<?php

      $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM recruits WHERE rct_app_uid = {$user_id}";
      $result = query($sql); //What type of query runs as just query()? mysql_query would go here if this was mysql. Some Libraries offer this as a function, but since you didn't specify the library, I'm going to change it to mysql_query and proceed as if you're using mysql.

      //$rct_app_id = ['rct_app_id'];//This will never work.

       //You need this:
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          //We only expect one result
          $rct_app_id=$row['rct_app_id'];
       }

      if ($rct_app_id == 'uid') {

          echo  "Green Light";

      } else {

          echo  "No Go";
    }
function query($query)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}

?>
```

Comment: You still need to fix the if statement, which is currently comparing a variable to a string.

Comment: take a look at the while statement. I'm assigning the variable value there, so it's comparing the value of $rct_app_id to 'uid', perfectly legit

Comment: So you're saying the id number coming out of the database is going to be the string 'uid'. Really?

Comment: You're assuming the $rct_app_id is a number, 1, you can't assume that. as the field type is not specified. 2, the only other thing there is to compare it to in the script is the users session[uid]; which is being used to actually find the right row, making the sql lookup useless, unless he wants to simply make sure it's in the database, and if that's the case, there are far less intensive and easier methods for that.

Comment: Greg, big picture here.  If they are storing a recruit's application id as a string, and that string is equal to 'uid', then they have much bigger problems than we can solve here.